# Castle Strike PC game selection rectangle not displaying

Tags: gaming

I play Castle Strike on Windows 10 64-bit and I haven't got selection rectangle (selection rectangle is not visible) when dragging mouse for select units. On Windows 7 it works well.

Comment: That game was written for Windows 2000/XP. I would be very surprised if you can get it working properly on Windows 10.

Comment: You could try using Windows' compatibility settings to see if that'd get it working correctly. There's no promises though.

Comment: Combatibility settings doesn't work, however, I have 2 computers with Win 7 where it works so I play it here (I just wanted to play this game on my new laptop with Win 10).

Answer (score 0):

Being a (truly) older game (circa 2003), Windows 10 may not be suitable for it.

You may wish to look at running a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)-based [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (either Windows XP or 7). After setting up the virtual machine and installing Windows, you would simply install the game onto that VM. VirtualBox is free, so as long as you have an extra copy of Windows lying around, this might be a solution.